# Nginx location regex for any uri path and proxy to /

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a site http://example.com and I need to route all requests for any path like http://example.com/* to /

I have working code for exact 2 paths:

```
location ~ ^/(test1|test2) {
  rewrite ^/(test1|test2)$ / break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
  
}
```

But for wildcard it doesn't work:

```
location ~ ^/(.*) {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ / break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
  
}
```

Is it wrong regex or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
location ~ /(.+) {
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/;
}
```

This location includes any path except for the root.

Comment: root already serving: location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

Comment: Updated. Please check again.

Comment: giving 404 even on main page

Comment: Where do you want locations other than the root to be proxied? isn't it `http://127.0.0.1/`

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: What is the result of `curl http://127.0.0.1/`? Isn't it `404`?

Comment: yes it is 404 not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252547/discussion-between-andromeda-and-arturius).